# Is XSS possible with handsontable and no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, xss, handsontable

My webpage has the php extension, but there is no php code in it. There is `handsontable` and user would insert some numbers and get some cool `JS` effects on the same page. When I was writing the code for comments, I used `strip_tags` as a protection, but that was working for `PHP`. Now , I am curious if there is any danger leaving `handsontable` as it is?

Comment: JS executes on the client's computer. I don't think there is any danger. Are worried about $_SESSION?

Comment: I know that. Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't send data back to your serer there is no danger for that. Simple. You can add simple textarea into your page but without form - nothing will happen. This same is in Handsontable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the question is, can a visitor alter the content in a way that another visitor will load something to their browser that was not intended by developers. If it's purely client side and  if you do not accept any user inputs, I think its pretty safe. If you have any unused php scripts, remove them.

Comment: I do accept user input in a way: handsontable accepts values and then, some `JS` effects happen. There is no PHP code like `<?php ... ?>`, but the file's extension is php. Is it possible that somebody would type in some malicious javascript into handsontable cells, and would that be any danger?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I don't think so since you will not accept any user inputs. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet is a good reference btw.

Comment: @Alix Axel told me in one of the previous discussions that this http://xkcd.com/327/ is still possible...